# Company B plagiarises the same element higher segment of car model of Company A and puts it in a different segment

Tags: phrases, expressions

Disclaimer: This is purely an hypothetical example for explanation purpose only. I do not wish to malign toyota or chevy for any reason.

A hypothetical example:

Chevy release its best exterior design in its premium sedan segment called Chevy XYZ

Toyota than copies the same exterior design of the Chevy XYZ and put it in its Small-sized Sedan segment naming it Toyota ABC

This is done so as to not appear pure plagiarism as it (Toyota ABC) does form a direct completion to the original (chevy XYZ) model and pretty much let it fly under the radar.

I want to know here what has toyota done is plagiarism. I want a specific phase. Am I right in saying its is Cross segment step-down plagiarism.

Comment: See https://foundationlaw.com/car_design_patents/ as a starting point. It’s a matter of law, not language.

Comment: To avoid "maligning Toyota or Chevy" , you can make up names , like "Car maker Tuyutu" & "Car maker Choxyo" which will not conflict.

Comment: It's still patent infringement if you take a patent for a luxury car feature and put it in a cheap car. The patent applies to the invention, not the saleable unit it is part of (e.g. a patent for a windshield wiper applies to all cars and everything else with a windshield). This is a legal issue: even questions about legal nomenclature probably belong on Law SE.

Comment: Is it *exactly* the same design? Or is it smaller in some way? Slightly modified? Generally the same approach with some differences in implementation? Consequences of all those can be discussed on Law SE. In common speech this could be anything from "inspired by" to "borrowed" to "ripped-off". While plagiarism technically matches, it's not commonly used in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is *[industrial design infringement](https://www.legalline.ca/legal-answers/industrial-design-infringement/)*.